# Загрузка строк в стек

Tags: .net, строки, стек

Почему не получается загрузить 2 строки в стек так:
(IL)

```
.assembly Hello {}
.method public static void Main() cil managed
{
   .entrypoint
   .maxstack 8
   ldstr "Hello, world!"
   ldstr "Hello, world!2"
   call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
   ret
}
```

Comment: Я предполагал, что так должно быть, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку даже без вызова функции.

Comment: Ой, неправильно изъяснил. Компиляция проходит успешно, с запуском проблемы: https://pp.vk.me/c604629/v604629034/276d4/v6F2Zb2_S0g.jpg

Comment: То есть проблема в том, что ret не может вернуть стек с 2-мя значениями?

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой содержательный ответ)

Comment: @Mike оформили бы уже полноценный ответ, информации в ваших комментариях для этого достаточно

Comment: @rdorn Ну я немного опасался написать что то не так по интуиции. Потому как про существование IL узнал из вопроса :) Я понимаю, что происходит как то похоже на то что я написал, но то что оно буквально так немного сомневаюсь (хотя про соглашения о вызовах в IL сейчас нашел немного)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ldstr` загружает в стек адрес строки. По соглашению о вызовах применяемых в IL очистку стека, т.е. удаление из него аргументов функции производит вызываемая функция. `WriteLine` ожидает получить один параметр и удаляет из стека одно значение. Вы же кладете в стек 2 значения, значит на момент выполнения ret у вас в стеке остается одно лишнее.

На момент вызова любой функции на вершине стека лежит адрес возврата, куда `ret` должен вернуть управление при завершении функции. В момент выполнения `ret` берет адрес возврата с вершины стека и производит переход по этому адресу. Если в момент выполнения `ret` в стеке окажется лишнее значение (которое вы туда положили и никто его от туда не забрал) то `ret` не будет знать куда надо возвращаться и произойдет аварийное завершение программы.